# Higher frequencies with getByteFrequencyData in Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, microphone, getusermedia, spectrum, audiocontext

I'm trying to display the sound spectrum from the microphone using JavaScript. The code below works on my notebook (Firefox and Chrome browser). On my phone (Chrome browser) it works, too, but only up to approx. 5 kHz. Higher frequencies are missing. My phone is capable of recording higher frequencies. I checked that using several apps. For the stuff I'm trying to do, I really need the higher frequencies as well.
Now the question is: Is this a limitation of Chrome mobile? How can I overcome this limitation? Or did I miss something and the error is in my code?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>soundtest.htm</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas class="visualizer" width="1024" height="384"></canvas>
<script>
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
var canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var actx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var analyser = actx.createAnalyser();
analyser.minDecibels = -120;
analyser.maxDecibels = -10;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
analyser.fftSize = 2048;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia(
      {
         audio: true
      },
      function(stream) {
         source = actx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
         source.connect(analyser);
        frame();
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log('getUserMedia error: ' + err);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia is not supported by your browser!');
}

function frame() {
  drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  var freqArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  document.title = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqArray);

  // Clear background
  ctx.fillStyle = '#F0F0F0';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw vertical lines at 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 kHz
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#808080';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  var h = canvas.width * 2 / actx.sampleRate;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 20000; i += 5000) {
    var x = i * h;
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw spectrum
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  var barWidth = canvas.width / analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  for(var i = 0; i < analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++) {
    var barHeight = freqArray[i] * canvas.height / 255;
    ctx.fillRect(barWidth * i, canvas.height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419446